# How to set up the front end to access the routing in express?

Tags: javascript, express, frontend

I have an example for routing , where I do not understand, how to understand and utilize it. How do I have to set up my front end to access `/tracks` and pass in the `trackID`?

What I tried for the front end:

```
const API = (window.location.hostname === '127.0.0.1' || window.location.hostname === 'localhost') ? 'http://localhost:3000/tracks' :"https://blooming-bayou-96051.herokuapp.com/tracks/5f873b8ddd81e84cf2e21a80" 
//URL to server

function stream(){
  fetch(API, {
    method: "GET",
    header: {
      "Accept": "application/vnd.heroku+json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => console.log('response: ', res.json(res)))
}
```

A minimal example of the backend:

```
const app = express();

app.use('/tracks', trackRoute);

trackRoute.get('/:trackID', (req, res) => {
   //whatever
})
```

Best regards

Comment: `var API = const API = ...` ?

Comment: Since you're trying to pass a trackID in the /tracks/:trackID endpoint, you have to pass the parameter from your front-end request (fetch API request), example: `http://localhost:3000/tracks/100`. In your example there is not trackID sent from your fetch request.

Comment: okey. So I will only have to add /trackID to the URL, and it gets directed to /tracks/:trackid.